# Searching in vector of pairs

Tags: algorithm

I have a vector of pairs (datatype=double), where each pair is (a,b) and a less than b.For a number x, I want to find out number of pair in vector, where a<=x<=b.

Consider the vector size about 10^6.

**My Approach**
Sort the vector pair and perform a lower_bound operation for x over "a" in pair then iterate from start till my lower bound value and check for values of "b" which satisfies condition of x<=b.
**Time Complexity**
N(LogN) where N is vector size.
**Issue**
I have to perform this over large queries where this approach becomes inefficient.So is there any better solution to decrease the time complexity.
Sorry for my poor English and question formatting.

Comment: If you only have one `x`, the straightforward method of checking each pair in their original order is just O(N).

Comment: When you say the queries are "large" do you mean you have multiple `x` values to query at the same time?  Or you have only one `x` value and the vector is large (you mentioned 1 million pairs)?

Comment: @JohnZwinck i have multiple x values for queries and i have to query this in a large vector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the previous answer, here's a suggestion how to prepare the ranges to optimize the subsequent lookup. The idea boils down to precomputing the result for all significantly different input values, but being smart about when values don't differ significantly.

To illustrate what I mean, let's consider this sequence of ranges:

```
1, 3
1, 8
2, 4
2, 6
```

The prepared output structure then looks like this:

```
1, 2 -> 2
2, 3 -> 4
3, 4 -> 3
4, 6 -> 2
6, 8 -> 1
```

For any number in the range `1, 2`, there are two matching ranges in the initial sequence. For any number in the range `2, 3`, there are four matches, etc. Note that there are five ranges here now, because some of the input ranges partially overlapped. Since for every range here the end value is also the start value of the next range, the end value can be optimized out. The result then looks like a simple map:

```
1 -> 2
2 -> 4
3 -> 3
4 -> 2
6 -> 1
8 -> 0
```

Note here that the last range didn't have one following, so the explicit zero becomes necessary. For the values before the first, that is implied. In order to find the result for a value, just find the key that is less than or equal to that value. This is a simple O(log n) lookup.

Comment: Your answer is perfect when it comes to point that ranges are integer values,but as i mentioned data type is double ,so i don't think we can make a output structure.

Comment: There's no reason why this shouldn't work with real numbers.

Comment: Sry for that,your approach will work for real numbers too,the thing is I would just need to update my query procedure for real numbers

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, if you just did a simple scan over the pairs, you would have O(n) complexity! The O(n log n) comes from sorting and for a one-off operation this is just overhead. This might even be the best way to do it, if you don't reuse the results and even if you just perform a few queries, it might still be better than sorting. Make sure you allow yourself to switch out the algorithm.

Anyhow, let's consider that you need to make many queries. Then, one relatively obvious step to improve things is to not iterate step-by-step after sorting. Instead, you can do a binary search for the lower bound. Simply partition the sequence into halves. The lower bound can be found in either half, which you can determine by looking at the middle element between the partitions. Recurse until you found the first element that can not possibly contain the value you search, because its start value is already greater.

Concerning the other direction, things are not that easy. Just because you sorted the ranges by the start value doesn't imply that the end values are sorted, too. Also, ranges that match and ranges that don't can be mixed in the sequence, so here you will have to perform a linear scan.

Lastly, some notes:

- You could parallelize this algorithm using multithreading.
- Depending on your number of searches M in your outer loop, you could also switch the outer loop with the inner one. That means that for every pair of the input vector, you check each of the M search values whether they fall within the range. This might be better, in particular when the M searches fit into the CPU cache.

Comment: can you explain your point of  binary search for lower and upper bound

Comment: Actually, no. You can reduce the number of candidates by searching for the first range that your value `v` can't be contained in because `v < a` using a binary search. That doesn't work for the upper bound though, The approach I had in mind was flawed. I fixed that in the above answer. The remaining complexity is thus still O(n), although runtime may be actually reduced. I have a different idea though, but I'll put that into a second answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very typical style problem in for segment trees, binary indexed trees, interval trees.

There are two operations that you have to carry out on an array `arr`.

You have two operations on an array `arr`:
1. **Range update**: `Add(a, b): for(int i = a; i <= b; ++i) arr[i]++`
2. **Point query** : `Query(x):  return arr[x]`

Alternately, you could formulate your problem slightly cleverly.
1. **Point Update**: `Add(a, b): arr[a]++; arr[b+1]--;`
2. **Range Query**:  `Query(x):  return sum(arr[0], arr[1] ..... arr[x]);`

In each of the cases above, you have one O(n) operation and one O(1) operation.

For the second case, the query is essentially a prefix sum calculation. Binary Indexed Trees are especially efficient at this task.

[Tutorial for Binary Indexed Trees](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/data-structures/advanced-data-structures/fenwick-binary-indexed-trees/tutorial/)

**IMPORTANT IDEA: ARRAY COMPRESSION**

You did mention that the vector size is about `10^6`, so there is a chance that you may not be able to create an array that big. If you are able to create a set that consists of all the `a`s and `b`s and `x`s beforehand, then you can translate them into numbers from `1` to `size of set`.

**SUPER CLEVER IDEA: MO's ALGORITHM**

This is only allowed if you are allowed to solve the problem offline. What that means is that you can take all the query points `x` as input, solve them in any order as you like and store the solution, and then print the solution in the correct order.

Please mention if this is your situation, and only then will I elaborate further on this. But Binary Indexed Trees are going to be more efficient than Mo's algorithm.

**EDIT:**

Because your interval values are of type `double`, you must convert them to integers before you use my solution. Let me give an example,

`Intervals = (1.1 to 1.9), (1.4 to 2.1)
Query Points = 1.5, 2.0`

Here all the points that are of interest are not all the possible doubles, but just the above numbers `= {1.1, 1.4, 1.5, 1.9, 2.0, 2.1}`

If we map them into positive integers:

```
1.1 --> 1
1.4 --> 2
1.5 --> 3
1.9 --> 4
2.0 --> 5
2.1 --> 6
```

Then you could use segment trees/binary indexed trees.

Comment: I mentioned that dataype is double so i think i can't use your solution

Answer (score -1):

For each pair a,b you can decompose so that a=+1 and b=-1 for the number of ranges valid for a particular value. Then in becomes a simple O(log n) lookup to see how many ranges encompass the search value.

Comment: can you please elaborate or give an example?

Comment: @PunitJain it's late and I'm unable to flesh out a more thorough answer at this time. But the principle is sound.